# jQuery Ui not importing "auto" classes when using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So, basically I'm importing jQuery Ui content into my index.html file, from another html file, using AJAX in jQuery.
It seems that 'Ui' adds classes to the html tags, I'm guessing it does it when the DOM is loaded But when AJAX pulls in the content it doesn't bring the extra classes from Ui.

Is there some way to get this sorted?

Something simple that I'm missing?

I can't seem to find info on the problem anywhere.

```
var $prodBut=$('#prodButton');

    $prodBut.click(function(){
    $('main').load('products2.html main > *');
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you use `.load()` with a CSS selector, jQuery does not run any of the JavaScript found in the content. It has no way of knowing whether running just the scripts found in the DOM subtree selected by the selector can actually work without error, because it may rely on other `<script>` tags *not* selected.

Last time I checked there was no option to alter that behavior.

Comment: Ah right..  I suppose I'll just copy the class names, and info, from the console and manually add them. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

So the "simple thing" I was missing was that I needed to add a callback function

```
var $prodBut=$('#prodButton');

$prodBut.click(function(){
    $('main').load('products2.html main > *', null, onLoadProducts);
});
```

In my case I was trying to add jQueryUI tabs and so the callback function was just:

```
function onLoadProducts(){
    $('#contProductTabs').tabs();
}
```

I thought I knew what callback functions did, but I guess I didn't really understand until I needed to use one..